# Laravel Print from form not returning any value

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on my laravel form to output the values on the same page. Which is not happening, when i press the submit button. I dont get any error, but nothing happens.

routes.php

```
         Route::get('/', function() 
        {

            return View::make('index');

        });

        Route::post('index', array('as' => 'index', function()
        {

            return  View::make('index');
        }));
```

index.blade. php

```
@extends('master')
@section('container')
<h1> Hey </h1>
<table>
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/')) }}
<tr> 
    <td>    {{ Form::label('bassengId', "Basseng Id") }}  </td>
    <td>  {{ Form::text('bassengId') }} </td>
</tr>

  <tr>

  <td>  {{ Form::label('BadendePT', "Badende Per time")}} </td>
  <td>  {{ Form::text('BadendePT') }} </td>

 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>  {{ Form::label('Temp'), "Temperatur" }} </td>
  <td>  {{ Form::text('Temp') }} </td>

 </tr>

    <tr> 
  <td>  {{ Form::label('LuftTemp', "Luft Temperatur") }} </td>
   <td> {{ Form::text('LuftTemp') }} </td>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td> <td>   {{ Form::submit ('lagre') }} </td> </td>

 </tr>
{{ Form::close() }}
</table>
@endsection
```

Comment: When you submit your form, it's looking for a route::post('/',... route. And you don't have that route.

Answer (score 2):

Your form looks fine. Your action url is '/'.Do this:

Add post route and do this

```
Route::post('/', function() 
    {

        //get your input from form
        $input= Input::all();
         //you can check this simply here using print_r($input); die();
        //pass it to view page now
        return View::make('index')->with('data','$input');

    });
```

Now in your index.blade.php  do this in section part if you want to show output on same page.

```
@extends('master')
@section('container')
<h1> Hey </h1>
<table>
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/')) }}
 <tr> 
  <td>    {{ Form::label('bassengId', "Basseng Id") }}  </td>
  <td>  {{ Form::text('bassengId') }} </td>
</tr>

<tr>

   <td>  {{ Form::label('BadendePT', "Badende Per time")}} </td>
   <td>  {{ Form::text('BadendePT') }} </td>

 </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>  {{ Form::label('Temp'), "Temperatur" }} </td>
   <td>  {{ Form::text('Temp') }} </td>

  </tr>

   <tr> 
  <td>  {{ Form::label('LuftTemp', "Luft Temperatur") }} </td>
  <td> {{ Form::text('LuftTemp') }} </td>

   </tr>
 <tr>
    <td> <td>   {{ Form::submit ('lagre') }} </td> </td>

 </tr>
 {{ Form::close() }}
  </table>

  @if($data)
    // show your data now
 {{$data->Temp}}
 {{$data->LuftTemp}}
   @endif

@endsection
```

Comment: I get error: undefined variable: data in the view file.

Comment: See updated code. Are you getting input at your route. try printing there. After that follow above code

Comment: When does this error come. When you post form or before that ?

Comment: When I try to load the index page. (before)

Comment: Alright remove that $data part from index page. You will get form. give input and check on route wheather it is coming there or not.

Comment: I new to laravel, how do I check in route if the data is comming or not ?

Comment: i have mentioned in my answer. Give input and it will go to you post('/') route, then inside function write after $input line ; print_r($input); die();

Comment: Still not displaying any of the data, although no errors this time.

Comment: In laravel Route's have first priorty, whenever we render some page suppost('/'). ,call will go to route::get('/') and render page or do action whatever we specift in Route. Same in case of post action. If we have form of post action. whenever we submit , it will go to corresponding post route and do the action. This is code cycle Route->controller->view.

Comment: check this tutorial http://culttt.com/2013/08/19/creating-forms-in-laravel-4/ . Even laravel documentation is ver neat and easy to understand.

Comment: I see! I am still very unsure why this is not working when I press the submit buttom and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('index', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});

{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'index') }}
    // ...
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Still not working, updated my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902782/passing-input-form-from-a-page-to-itself

Comment: Trying it to work, but got error after submitting form.